# Привет. У меня есть задача по переходу по Route получить всех пользователей. PHP. Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, service

*Привет я только начал изучать Symfony. У меня вопрос. У меня есть сущность с name, surname, email. У меня есть данные в БД, мне нужно по переходу по Route показывались все польвотели с их данными(name, surname, email).
Я пробывал работать через модели, а потом в Service принимать Repository и в методе писать FindBy,array_map. Но когда я переходил в Контроллере по Route у меня былa пустая страница.
Так же я пробовыл через ДТОшки DTOBuilder и работать через менеджер, но у меня не получилось.*

### ***Entity***

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;


#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: false)]
    private string $name;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: false)]
    private string $surname;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: false)]
    private string $password;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, unique: true),
    email
    ]
    private string $email;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "json", nullable: false)]
    private array $roles = [];

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'authorization_count', type: 'integer', nullable: false)]
    private int $authorizationCount = 0;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSurname(): string
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $surname
     */
    public function setSurname(string $surname): void
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword(string $password): void
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail(string $email): void
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }
```

### ***Database***

[image: Картинка БД]

Если есть вопросы по задаче пишите.Буду благодарен любому совету

### Repository

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<User>
 *
 * @method User|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method User|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method User[]    findAll()
 * @method User[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    public function add(User $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    public function remove(User $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }
        public function save(): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
    }
}
```

### Manager

```
<?php

namespace App\Manager;


use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;

/**
 * Class UserManager.
 */
class UserManager
{
    /**
     * @param UserRepository $userRepository
     */
    public function __construct
    (
        private UserRepository $userRepository
    )
    {
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @param bool $flush
     * @return User
     */
    public function create(User $user, bool $flush = true): User
    {
        $this->userRepository->add($user, $flush);

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @return User
     */
    public function update(User $user): User
    {
        $this->userRepository->save();

        return $user;

    }
}
```

### Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use App\DTOBuilder\Type\UserRegistrationTypeDTOBuilder;
use App\Form\Type\UserRegistrationType;
use App\Manager\UserManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;




/**
 * Class UserRegistrationController.
 */
class UserRegistrationController extends AbstractController
{

    #[Route('/helloUser', name: 'hello_user')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return new Response('hello, User');
    }

    #[Route('/logout', name: 'logout')]
    public function logout()
    {
    }


    #[Route('/reg', name: 'user_registration')]
    public function registration(Request $request, UserManager $userManager, UserRegistrationTypeDTOBuilder $registrationTypeDTOBuilder): Response
    {
        $userRegistrationForm = $this->createForm(UserRegistrationType::class);

        $userRegistrationForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($userRegistrationForm->isSubmitted() && $userRegistrationForm->isValid()) {
            $user = $registrationTypeDTOBuilder->buildEntity($userRegistrationForm->getData());
            $userManager->create($user);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('info_user', ['userEmail' => $user->getEmail(), 'userName' => $user->getName()]);

        }

        return $this->render('user_registration/registration_page.html.twig', [
            'userRegistrationForm' => $userRegistrationForm->createView(),
        ]);

    }

    #[Route('/info/{userEmail}/{userName}', name: 'info_user')]
    public function getUserInfo(string $userEmail, string $userName, UserManager $userManager): Response
    {
        return new Response('Привет ' . $userName . '.<br/> Ты зарегистрировался.<br/> Почта: ' . $userEmail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Сущность вы приложили...а где все остальное?..

Comment: @МихаилРебров Приложил Repository и Manager

Comment: Контроллер, может приложите?..

Comment: В котроллере, нунжно вызывать сервис для вызова всех польвотьелей как я понимаю. Котроллер пуст.

Comment: @МихаилРебров добавил контроллер для регистрации пользвателей. Это единственный контроллер, который есть в моем проекте.

Comment: начните с того, что в репозитории, добавьте метод, который получает коллекцию `$this->findAll();`